# How to manage MVC AJAX responses when in a jQuery dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, actionlink

Here is my problem:

Inside a jQuery dialog I have the following code:

```
<%:Ajax.ActionLink("Yes", "SendClaim", "Claim", new { id = Model.ExpenseId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "dialog" }, new { @class = "button" })%>
```

When stuff fails in the controller based on roles I return a partial view that replaces the existing dialog (see `UpdateTargetId = "dialog"`).

When everything works I want to do a redirect to another page (an index of all claims) to stop the user performing additional actions but this entire page is **rendered inside the jQuery dialog** due to it being an ajax request with an update id.

What is the correct way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit of a novice, but I find I have more control with the following approach instead of using `Ajax.ActionLink`. Hopefully it helps and I have understood what you want to do correctly.

Claim Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public Json Send(int expenseId)
{
// Check user stuff
if(valid)
// do stuff
    return new Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
else
    return new Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

jQuery

```
function submitClaim() {
    $.ajax({
                       url: "/Claim/Send",
                       type: "POST",
                       dataType: "json",
                       data: { 'expenseId': <%=Model.ExpenseId> },
                       success: function (data) {
                           if(data) { // if successful, redirect
                               document.location = "Claim/Index";
                           }
                           else { //load your partial view into your dialog
                               $("#idOfYourDialog").load('Claim/Error/');
                           }
                       },
                           error: function (xhr) { }
                       });
}
```

html

```
<a href="javascript:submitClaim()">Submit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Returned an 'All OK' dialog and had the following javascript when the user clicks the ok button:

```
function redirect() {
   document.location = "<%:(String)ViewBag.Redirect %>";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click(function() {
        redirect();
   });
});
```

Seems unavoidable - you can't seem to do an `RedirectToAction` when the controller action has been called from `Ajax.ActionLink` as the response will be stuck into the updatetargetid.

Comment: Not going to accept this as the answer just yet incase others can come up with a better idea.